# Avoid duplicates while syncing offline data in mobile app to server

Tags: android, rest

We have a mobile application. There is a sales module. It calls the sales rest api to create a sales order.

Format of the sales api POST request:

```
//server generates primary key. there is no support for request id currently
{
    "customer_id" : 1,
    "items" : [
               { "item_id" : 123 },
               { "item_id" : 456} 
               ],
    "store_id" : 10,
    "sale_time" : "2019-10-01 13:45:01"

}
```

As we have to support offline mode, all sales will be stored locally on the device and when the internet connection is available it will sync with the server.

But I got to know that http libraries can retry http request multiple times if the internet connectivity is poor. But this may cause to create multiple sales entry on the server.

How to implement syncing offline data properly given that server(rest api) generates the primary key for the new record? Updating existing record is fine as it has primary key generated by server but how to deal with new records without a primary key?

Scenario:

1. App is in offline mode
2. User creates a sales order and saves it locally
3. After sometime, say there is limited internet connectivity.
4. App fetches all yet to be synced records and calls rest API for each one.
5. Sales Rest API called for 1st record and app is waiting for response.
6. Internet connection fails, but server creates record and fails to notify the app
7. After few minutes say Internet connection is back, now app tries to call sales api for the 1st record again and receives success response as well. But there are two entries in the server.

How to fix this?

Comment: You have to maintain an unique `instanceId` for each sales record and check it in server side before insert to avoid duplicate. You can use `UUID` to generate unique id during creation of sales order. Hope this help you. Thanks

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman but this will need changes in the sales api to pass instanceid right?

Comment: Yes, you have to change the API. Without unique identifier how can you identify which is insert or not?

Comment: If it is not possible to change API, then you can try with the combination of `store_id` and `sale_time` to check uniqueness as a last hope. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to handle this

1)using sync-status

when you store the data in storage add one more flag as "sync-status" and the data type will be boolean default is false. and get only those data that have sync-status as false. if data successfully sends to server change status as true.

2)sever syn-date-time

if your server send you sync date-time then this will be possible, you need to check the date after server-sync-date-time that data only u need to sync with the server

Comment: I have upated question. Plz check scenario section

Comment: prem, I got your point, you can add the timeout for server response. if your server not responding within timeout you get fail status. or your server need to check the record exist or not and take action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky scenario. If you are having to deal with a single client communicating with an API, then simply passing a unique identifier to the API from the client and storing it, checking it before creating any future records will do the trick, as mentioned by Md. Asaduzzaman.

However, in a scenario where you have many clients using the same API, I would further extend this to include user information, so you know what client this request has come from. This is to avoid overlapping identifiers between clients. Yes GUIDs are unlikely to overlap, but it is possible.

This is cool, for creating new records for example, but what about updating existing records? In this case, you would also need something like a lastModifiedTime field both on the client and API, if the API lastModifiedTime is ahead of the client, then you have a conflict that needs to be dealt with.

You could perhaps have a single table in the API which is called EntitySyncStatus consisting of EntityTypeId, EntityId, ClientEntityId, UserId(or DeviceId), and lastModifiedTime could either be maintained in this table, or in the entity table.

This model will then support syncing multiple objects, without storing sync related fields on each individual entity, but also provide more flexibility and visibility.